# QJackCtrl Activate Patchbay persistence

Tags: sound, jack

I am trying to use Patchbay persistence with QJackCtrl to help manage my connections. However when I go to try and activate it it doesn't seem to create a file for me (for the settings). I also can't select any files.

[image]

I realize that patchbay requires a .xml file. Where do I get this file?

Comment: See http://www.rncbc.org/drupal/node/76

Answer (score 0):

I realized that one had to be created via Patchbay located when the program starts up.

[image]